# How to use new dropbox datastore API from chrome extension?

Tags: dropbox-api

I'm trying to use a new dropbox datastore API with my chrome extension. If used as specified in tutoria, auth will fail with error 400:

```
Invalid redirect_uri: "chrome-extension://anzbpdekhbhcbekwmfazaophjcaabshl/chrome_oauth_receiver.html". It must exactly match one of the redirect URIs you've pre-configured for your app (including the path)
```

If i add this URL to my app profile at dropbox website, all works fine. But "anzbpdekhbhcbekwmfazaophjcaabshl" is a computer-unique value, it will be different for each extension installation for each user. Is it possible to somehow fix this or dropbox datastore API is intended to be used on static websites where redirect url is known?

**Update 1**

Extension ID is random for manual/non-public extension installation.

**Update 2**

I have found a way to make extension ID persistent: just pack it, generate a public key fro private .pem key and set this key's base-64 encoded value as 'key' in manifest.

Comment: I thought that the extension ID (the part right after `chrome-extension://`) was *not* user- or computer-specific and remained the same everywhere the Chrome extension is installed.

Am I wrong?

Comment: Actually, extension ID is assigned by google upon registration in web store. But if you start extension manually, it is dynamically generated.

Comment: @smarx You was right: i have found a way to make ID persistent. Please make your comment an answer so i can accept it.

Comment: Could you post more info about using the datastore API in a chrome extension? I'm having trouble getting it set up.  You said you found a tutorial?

Comment: @jeremywho I found that i can make application ID persistent by adding "key" to manifest. This allows to use datastore api without any problems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Moving my comment to an answer (and see updates to the question for details):

I thought that the extension ID (the part right after chrome-extension://) was not user- or computer-specific and remained the same everywhere the Chrome extension is installed.

Answer (score 1):

I'm successfully using the Datastore API from a Firefox extension. The trick is to attach the dropbox scripts to an actual webpage, not a local page. I have a blank page hosted on my server, and the extension opens that page and attached the necessary scripts. From there it redirects the user to the Dropbox authentication page.

Once the user has authenticated I open the same page in a "headless" tab using the page-worker API. (I don't know if Chrome extensions have the equivalent functionality)

The redirect URL has to be https so you'll need to get an SSL certificate for it to work.

Comment: It's a good idea, but not suitable for offline chrome extensions (Dropbox API can be used offline).